# PHP mysql_query() Select with CONCATENATION

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I have the following php code:

```
mysql_query("SELECT a FROM b WHERE b.c = '".$_REQUEST['companyName']."'");
```

I also have a string:

```
$mynumbers = "AND b.question_code IN (1);";
```

How can I combine this string withing the mysql_query()?

Thanks,

Comment: /me casts hundreds of comments about stopping using `mysql_query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SELECT a FROM b WHERE b.c = '".$_REQUEST['companyName']."' " . $mynumbers);
```

But keep in mind that `AND GROUP BY all_surveys.question_code IN (1);` is incorrect sql and makes no sense.

Comment: just changed it. Trying it out now. Can you remove your edit?

Comment: @Sohel Mansuri: can I remove *what*? And what exactly have you changed?

Comment: No more GROUP BY in question. In order for people to understand, you should erase your edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this if you want more simplicity;

```
$sql="SELECT a FROM b WHERE b.c = '".$_REQUEST['companyName']."'";
$sql.=$mynumbers;

echo $sql;
```

Also as `zerkms` said your sql seems to be incorrect

Answer (score 0):

First is, you can not combine above two statements, the alternatively you can do like this-
//Here i assume that you want to concatenate 2nd condition on particular situation so you need to add if condition or else you can directly contcate it with "." (dot) operator.

> $query = "SELECT a FROM b WHERE b.c = '".$_REQUEST['companyName']."'";
>
> if(//your condition) $query .= "AND GROUP BY b.question_code IN (1);";
>
> mysql_query($query);

Answer (score 0):

**Dont use AND before Group By**

Try the following code,

```
$query  = "SELECT a FROM b WHERE b.c = '".$_REQUEST['companyName']."'";
$query .= " GROUP BY b.question_code IN (1)"
mysql_query($query)
```